# UI-Router nested - multiple views , hold a view and change another view the same time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Consider the layout below:
[image]

I've got two views, view `A` and view `B`. I'm trying to load user menu in `A view` and menu contents in `B view`.

I tried this:
First I loaded my menu in `A view`, then when I tried to view a menu , `ui-router` will make `A view` empty and load `B view`.

How could I hold `A view` state while `B view` state is changing?

Perhaps the way I'm doing this is totally wrong.

**Update 1:**
Here is my route config:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("login", {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            "login": {
                templateUrl: "./static/views/login.html",
                controller: loginController
            }
        }
    })
    .state("dashboard", {
        url: "/dashboard",
        views: {
            "view-a": {
                templateUrl: "./static/views/dashboard.html"
            }
        }

    })
    .state("test", {
        url: "/test",
        views: {
            "view-b": {
                templateUrl: "./static/views/test.html"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show how router is configured, we don't know how you are currently doing it

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want B to be a nested view of A. There a few differernt ways to achieve this, here are the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

This approach will give a possible route to view B at /dashboard/test

```
$stateProvider
.state("login", {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
        "login": {
            templateUrl: "./static/views/login.html",
            controller: loginController
        }
    }
})
.state("dashboard", {
    url: "/dashboard",
    views: {
        "view-a": {
            templateUrl: "./static/views/dashboard.html"
        }
    }

})
.state("dashboard.test", {
    url: "/test",
    views: {
        "view-b": {
            templateUrl: "./static/views/test.html"
        }
    }
});
```

Inside dashboard.html you can reference view-b by having `<div ui-view="view-b"></div>`

Comment: Great! I read so many documents none of them helped as much as you did.